# Spinner disable swipe to open

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Currently, a spinner opens when I perform a swipe gesture from its location, allowing me to select an item by releasing.

I would like to disable this, as it interferes with scrolling in ScrollLayout and ViewPager. The spinner should only open, under any circumstance, by a single tap, not by any gestures.

Comment: please post the code in question.

Comment: Haven't checked, but scrollview does have a onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent e) method that you can use to tell if the Spinner opens or not. You could try.

Comment: @inner_class7 It's a simple spinner, no additional code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue, and the quickest fix for me was to extend `Spinner` to something like the following. The idea is just to manually subscribe to and intercept all touch events and pass them to a `GestureDetector` which can decide for you when you have a tap - then you can activate the click functionality at that point. Seems to work fine on 6.0.1.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Spinner;

/**
 * Version of the Spinner class which doesn't open the popup on swipe
 */
public class SpinnerNoSwipe extends Spinner {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public SpinnerNoSwipe(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public SpinnerNoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public SpinnerNoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return performClick();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
}
```